# expanding a polynomial and collecting coefficients

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-manipulation

I'm trying to expand the following polynomial

```
  Expand[  (A1 a1 + A2 a2 + A3 a3 + A4 a4 + A5 a5 + A6 a6 + A7 a7 + A8 a8) 
           (D1 a1 + D2 a2 + D3 a3 + D4 a4 + D5 a5 + D6 a6 + D7 a7 + D8 a8)
         + (H1 a1 + H2 a2 + H3 a3 + H4 a4 + H5 a5 + H6 a6 + H7 a7 + H8 a8)
           (E1 a1 + E2 a2 + E3 a3 + E4 a4 + E5 a5 + E6 a6 + E7 a7 + E8 a8)]
```

and collect terms (for example, rewrite this as

```
  (A1 D1 + ....+ H1 E1) a1^2 + (A1 D2 + ....) a1 a2 + (A1 D3 + ... ) a1 a3 + ...
+ (A8 D8 + ... + ) a8^2 )
```

where I am thinking of the capital letters `A1, A2, ...., D1, D2, ... H1, H2, ..., E1, E2, ...` as some coefficients and `a_i`'s as variables.

I could do this by hand but what if, instead of having `8` variables and two terms, I have `k` variables and  `n` terms? Expanding the products and collecting terms by going through all the monomials by hand are doable but probably not that clever.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this?

```
expr = (A1 a1 + A2 a2 + A3 a3 + A4 a4 + A5 a5 + A6 a6 + A7 a7 + 
      A8 a8) (D1 a1 + D2 a2 + D3 a3 + D4 a4 + D5 a5 + D6 a6 + D7 a7 + 
      D8 a8) + (H1 a1 + H2 a2 + H3 a3 + H4 a4 + H5 a5 + H6 a6 + 
      H7 a7 + H8 a8) (E1 a1 + E2 a2 + E3 a3 + E4 a4 + E5 a5 + E6 a6 + 
      E7 a7 + E8 a8);

Collect[expr, {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8}]
```

---

Typing "collect" into the Documentation Center search field will bring up [this page](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Collect.html) as the first result.  It is a good idea to try a few keywords like this any time you are looking for a function.  Here it happens that the function is itself called `Collect`.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks Mr.Wizard. I tried that and it worked! =) I'm definitely going to come here to discuss Mathematica related questions, rather than going here: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/MathematicaSessions.html It's somewhat difficult teaching yourself how to use this program...

Comment: @math-visitor okay, I'm glad I guessed right. :-)  Be sure to make use of [chat] for getting help and especially *help using the help system*.  The documentation is usually quite thorough but *finding* the section you need can be a challenge.

Comment: I will definitely join Mathematica Chat in the the future, and for mathematica.SE members to help me with the online Mathematica help section!

Answer (score 6):

These operations will be helpful :

find maximal exponent for every variable :

```
Exponent[expr, {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8}]
```

> ```
> {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2}
> ```

find the coefficient of `a1^2` :

```
Coefficient[expr, a1, 2]
```

> ```
> A1 D1 + E1 H1
> ```

find all coefficients of `{a1^2, a2^2, a3^2, a4^2, a5^2, a6^2, a7^2, a8^2}`, e.g.

```
Column[ ({#, Coefficient[expr, #, 2]} & /@ {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8}]
```

> ```
>  {{a1, A1 D1 + E1 H1},
>   {a2, A2 D2 + E2 H2},
>   {a3, A3 D3 + E3 H3},
>   {a4, A4 D4 + E4 H4},
>   {a5, A5 D5 + E5 H5},
>   {a6, A6 D6 + E6 H6},
>   {a7, A7 D7 + E7 H7},
>   {a8, A8 D8 + E8 H8}}
> ```

In general you can simplify every coefficient working with `Collect`, however your example is "simple enough" :

```
Collect[expr, {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8}, Simplify] === 
Collect[expr, {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8}]
```

> ```
> True
> ```